# My center div keeps going down

Tags: css, html, center

How can I make my center stay on the top and the red stripe on the left?

http://jsfiddle.net/9G8aw/

CSS for the center div looks like this:

```css
#center {
    width:840px;
    margin:0 auto;
    float:left;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    border-radius:15px;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Great first question ( even included a fiddle! ) I hope things go well for you. I gave you an updated fiddle in my answer below, but I can adjust my fiddle if it doesn't solve your problem. I think it does.

Comment: is it possible to rearrange the order of your divs??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to give your center a percentage width `85% instead of a fixed 840px`

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I tried this, but than the center, gets smaller when the windows gets smaller. And I was looking forward to that the center could stay in One Piece.

Comment: in that case you MUST make sure that the viewport has a width that is larger than 1000px. because your left div would take 15% off and your center needs 840px. which, I think it's out of your control as you are not sure of user resolution.

Answer (score 1):

If you can rearrange your divs, You can do something like this.

put `<div id="left">...</div>` below `<div id="center">...</div>`

and use the same CSS you are using now.

**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9G8aw/2/)**

Comment: Thanks for your response. Problem with this is; that the center div, now is above the left div. While actually this is the thing I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Use min width

```
#container {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
min-width: 1200px;
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
Did actually did something good, but the problem now is. That the 'left'-div, doesn't adapt to the windows size. It also keeps in the same size. :(

Answer (score 0):

**Here you go:** http://jsfiddle.net/digitalextremist/eR7uu/

---

I changed `#center` to `float: right` and in that changed `width: 85%` also.

This solves your "static size" problem. I put `min-width: 640px` in the body but you can take it out.

Again, welcome to StackOverflow!

**Edited:** http://jsfiddle.net/digitalextremist/eR7uu/1/

```
.header {
    white-space:nowrap;
    padding: 0px 5%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Problem with this is; that the buttons in the center div, won't stay on one line if the windows gets smaller.

Comment: Added an update. Rather than use `min-width`, I used `nowrap` which you will see in the updated fiddle.